# How to pass title (or other parameter) to class file

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing, class-options

I know LaTeX just to the point of making simple documents and modifying simple characteristics of a document's layout. Now I'm creating a class for a kind of document in order not to have to copy a huge preamble in every document, and I don't know to achieve what I want to do. First of all, the class inherits from the `article` class, uses otf fonts so I'm compiling with XeLaTeX, and uses the fancyhdr package.

I want to specify the `fancyhdr` headers inside the `.cls` file because they're all going to have the same style, so I would like to include in the `.cls` file the lines:

```
\lhead[<even output>]{<odd output>}
\chead[<even output>]{<odd output>}
\rhead[<even output>]{<odd output>}
```

What's inside, though, would have to be parameters that would be specified in the `.tex` file, like the document's title, or the author's name, or other stuff. How could I pass this kinds of arguments to the `.cls` file. If a general solution is given (in order to learn LaTeX besides being able to do what I want), I would very much appreciate it too.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

As it can be seen in the article class file `article.cls` the above parameters can be called via `\@author`, `\@title` and so on. The below answer by Christian answers what I asked in the comments, and shows how to create different parameters in the class file that could be defined from the `.tex` file.

Comment: Did you look into `article.cls` as a starter?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, I feel very embarrased to say I didn't. I saw it uses `\@author` and so on. Is that general? How could I define in the class a "parameter" (I don't know how to call it) so I could access it from the cls via that method? Because the article class doesn't define author and title (I guess they're standard TeX parameters).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Should I add those questions to the original question?

Comment: I'll try to provide a solution, give me some minutes ;-)

Comment: the `\@author` etc commands are defined using `\author` etc. They are no class options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class

```
\ProvidesClass{mysuperclass}
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}%

\def\docauthorname{A. U. Thor}%
\def\docname{\jobname.tex}%
\def\docdate{\today}%


\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}{docdate}[\today]{%
  \def\docdate{#1}%
}

\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}{author}[A. U. Thor]{%
  \def\docauthorname{#1}%
}
\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}{docname}[]{%
  \def\docname{#1}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExecuteOptionsX{author,docdate}
\ProcessOptionsX%

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\lhead[\docauthorname]{\docauthorname}%
\chead[\docdate]{\docdate}%
\rhead[]{\docname}%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
}
\endinput
```

The class driver file:

```
\documentclass[docdate=1/1/2016,author=Me,docname=yelostfile]{mysuperclass}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will add the second question to the original post to make it coherent with this answer. Thank you again.